# Issue with custom UITableViewCell: UITextFields clearing when scrolled out of view- dequeuing problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell wherein I have methods for adding a textfield, images, animations, padding etc. to the cell.

In my ViewController I set up the cells as needed, catering for specific needs such as the first and last cell having different images and placeholder text than the rest of the cells in the UITableView.

My original problem was that when the table was dequeuing the cells and reusing them their order was being changed incorrectly, however currently I've solved that problem, but what happens now is that the text in UITextFields in the custom cells is removed/re-ordered when the tableview is scrolled out of view. Ideally I want the user to enter text into the textfield and it stay in that particular cell permanently.

From what I've tried, I guess I've got a problem with dequeuing my cells and my textfield delegates, where am I going wrong?? Are my textfield editingbegun/changed/ended methods being called in the right place in the SearchBarTableViewCell.m or should they be in the exploreViewController.m?

Here is where I'm setting up my custom cell and also my cellForRowAtIndex method where it's being implemented:

SEARCHBARTABLEVIEWCELL.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    //add search bar
    self.searchBar = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 280, 40)];
    self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:20.0f];
    [self.searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    [self.searchBar setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    self.searchBar.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0  alpha:1.0];
    self.searchBar.tintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0  alpha:1.0];
    self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:73.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0  alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
//    [self.contentView addSubview:self.searchBar];
    [self.searchBar addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(editingChanged:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [self.searchBar addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(editingBegun:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
    [self.searchBar addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(editingEnded:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

    //add the left padding and the left-hand icon to the searchbar textfield
    self.searchBarSpacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 20)];
    _searchBarIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0,15, 20)];

    _searchBarIcon.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [self.searchBarSpacerView addSubview:_searchBarIcon];
    [self.searchBar setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    _searchBarIcon.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0/255.0 green:173.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0  alpha:1.0];
    [_searchBar setLeftView:self.searchBarSpacerView];
    [self.searchBarSpacerView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    //add the far-right padding to the searchbar textfield
    self.searchBarPaddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
    self.searchBar.rightView = self.searchBarPaddingView;
    _searchBar.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [self.searchBarPaddingView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    //setup the "+" sign for the last cell in the tableview
    self.addRowButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.size.width - 30,10, 40, 40)];
    self.addRowButtonIcon = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [self.addRowButton addSubview:self.addRowButtonIcon];
    [self.searchBar addSubview:self.addRowButton];

    //setup the "between" and "and" text labels
    self.and = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 35.5, 40)];
    self.and.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:20.0f];
    self.and.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:159.0/255.0 green:159.0/255.0 blue:159.0/255.0  alpha:1.0];

    return self;
}

- (IBAction)editingBegun:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%li + %li", (long)self.rows, (long)self.tag);

    [self delegate];

    if (self.tag == 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.searchBarIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-90));
                         }completion:nil];

        if (sender.text.length > 0) {

            [self.and setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 35.5, 40)];
            [self.searchBarSpacerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 20)];
            self.and.hidden = YES;

        }

        NSLog(@"FIRSTCELL");
    }
    else if(self.tag <= self.rows-2){

        if (sender.text.length > 0) {

            [self.and setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 35.5, 40)];
            [self.searchBarSpacerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 20)];
            self.and.hidden = YES;

        }

        NSLog(@"MIDDLECELL");
    }
    else if(self.tag == self.rows -1 ){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.searchBarIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
                         }completion:nil];

        if (sender.text.length > 0) {

            [self.and setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 35.5, 40)];
            [self.searchBarSpacerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 20)];
            self.and.hidden = YES;

        }

        NSLog(@"LASTCELL");
    }
}

- (IBAction)editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{

    [self delegate];

//    NSLog(@"Editing...");
}

- (IBAction)editingEnded:(UITextField *)sender
{

    [self delegate];

    NSLog(@"Editing ended");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.searchBarIcon.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0));
                     }completion:nil];

    NSString *rawString = [sender text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    if ([trimmed length] != 0) {
        // Text was NOT empty or only whitespace.

            if (sender.text.length > 0) {
                NSLog(@" and in the new textField");

                 if (self.tag == 0){

                    [sender addSubview:self.and];

                     self.and.hidden = NO;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                                          delay:0.0f
                                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                     animations:^{

                                         [self.between setFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 80, 40)];

                                         [self.searchBarSpacerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45+self.between.frame.size.width+4, 20)];

                                     }completion:nil];

                 } else if (self.tag > 0) {

                     [sender addSubview:self.and];
                     self.and.hidden = NO;

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f
                                           delay:0.0f
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^{

                                          [self.and setFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 35.5, 40)];

                                          [self.searchBarSpacerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 45+self.and.frame.size.width+4, 20)];

                                      }completion:nil];
                        self.addRowButton.hidden = NO;

                     //set the padding view to accommodate the "+" button
                     [self.searchBarPaddingView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];
                     NSLog(@"%f",self.searchBarPaddingView.frame.size.width);
                 }
            }
    } else{
        NSLog(@"There are only blank spaces in this search box!");
        sender.text = @"";
        self.addRowButton.hidden = YES;
        [self.searchBarPaddingView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
    }
}

@end
```

EXPLOREVIEWCONTROLLER.M

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"searchCell";

    SearchBarTableViewCell *cell = [self.searchTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[SearchBarTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.searchBarIcon.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstCell"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        cell.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search between here...";
        cell.and.text = @"Between";


    } else if (indexPath.row == self.cells.count-1) {
        cell.searchBarIcon.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"lastCell"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        cell.and.text = @"and";


        cell.searchBar.placeholder = @"...and here";
        [cell.addRowButtonIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addRow"]];
        cell.addRowButton.hidden = YES;
        [cell.addRowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    } else {
        cell.and.text = @"and";

        cell.searchBarIcon.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyCell"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        cell.searchBar.placeholder = @"...and here";
        [cell.searchBarIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 2.5,15, 15)];

    }


    // Add utility buttons
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myLocation"]];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deleteCell"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.searchBar];

    cell.searchBar.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.rightUtilityButtons = rightUtilityButtons;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.rows = self.cells.count;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSLog(@"textfield tag %ld", (long)cell.searchBar.tag);

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid losing the value of each cell, it's common practice to create an array and store the values of each cell to the array. So the array will have global reach, it is best to declare it a global variable your class (EXPLOREVIEWCONTROLLER). In ExploreViewController.m, right before `@implementation`, add the following to accomplish this:

```
@interface ExploreViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *array;
}   

@end
```

Now, be sure to initialize the array somewhere in the class before using it. Common practice is to add this to your class's `init` method.

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Now in `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you can store the value of each textField by using `[array insertObject: textField.text atIndex: indexPath.row];`. A simply logic to follow in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to follow when dealing with stored values is to first check to see if the array (that represents your uitableView rows) has any values, and if it does, populate your fields with that data. Basic code representation of this is:

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
    NSString *textFieldText = [[NSString alloc] init];
    // Will retrieve text from array with the same index as the cell
    textFieldText = [array objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];    
}
```

The value of `textFieldText` can now be added added to the textField of the cell.

Comment: Can you explain what the intent of this is?  On the surface, it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @davetw12, thanks for the quick response, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @davetw12, this didn't seem to resolve the issue, and I'm not quite sure as to how your suggestion would fix my issue with the disappearing text if you could elaborate please?

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I misunderstood your question then. I thought that your cells were just appearing to be reordered. When that happened to me before, it was because after scrolling, cells would have views from adjacent cells placed over them. Wrong fix.

Comment: In any case, the code I submitted as an answer is used to remove all subviews after the original 3 (in my case).

Comment: I updated my answer to more reflect your cell subview removal. My hunch is that your issue occurs because in  dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier you don't specify your cell index path.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. As I scroll through the tableview the textfields change cells and eventually clear until all the cells are left with their original placeholders.

Comment: In that case, I think I might know the problem then. After text is entered in the textfield, do you save it anywhere? If aren't saving your textfield text to be recalled on scroll, that is your issue.

Comment: After some playing around I've managed to get it all sorted, thanks for point me in the right direction.